# How to download additional text-to-speech voices for later installation?

Tags: macos, text-to-speech

I would like to download additional text-to-speech voices for OS X to later install on multiple systems or systems without an internet connection.

Is this possible, or do I have to be online to download them through the System Preferences ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The downloaded voices are stored in **/System/Library/Speech/Voices**.

You can copy these between Macs. Download the desired voice on one Mac through System Preferences and copy it to the other Macs that you want.

Comment: how about the extended version (the 900 meg online file)

Comment: @Buscar If you mean Enhanced Dictation, that's dictation, not text-to-speech.